# Hi Guys, i want to install npm and getting Error in Laravel Project on hosting server -> npm install

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm

I have a Problem with *npm install* on a web hosting server. appearantly it requires node.js
I have already required laravel/ui and than php artisan ui:auth so it worked perfectly, but
than I tried  npm install and  it showed me -> npm command not found.

I know that it requires nodejs
to be installed,  but its a hosting server and not my personal pc. I tried to install node js
on hosting server but it has just created node based app and npm command still was not found.

please note that its a Hosting server otherwise i woud install node js and it woud be fine.
thanks

terminal cpanel:
bash: npm: command not found
bash: npm: command not found
bash: npm: command not found
bash: npm: command not found

error in browser :

Vite manifest not found at: /home/itcmzfcm/dash/public/build/manifest.json

Missing Vite Manifest File
Did you forget to run `npm install && npm run dev`?

Answer (score 0):

i think you try to publish project right ? if you doing this you need to publish your asset with [laravel mix](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix) or [npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-build) in you local pc then upload the project to cpanel

Comment: hey, i ve installed  npm locally, it works nicely, but than uploaded the application on webserver  and it does not work.  the error is caused by this                                                        @vite(['resources/sass/app.scss', 'resources/js/app.js'])         <--  so it requires npm && npm dev to be installed.  locally they work but on web server they dont.

Comment: Hey you need to upload your assets and node module folder

Comment: my assets folder with js css in it and node_modules folder are uploaded. but the same problem..

Comment: yes you are right sorry.  its becouse i had public folder in public_html folder.  but is it right way  to keep public folder inside of project root folder? and if not i probebly link tham somehow right ?